# regex for word with restricted number of occurrences for certain char

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble writing regex which matches:

- a word with characters from `a-z` but character `k` & `p` must not occur more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^[a-jl-oq-z]*(k|p)?[a-jl-oq-z]*(?!\1)(k|p)?[a-jl-oq-z]*$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jG5gQ6/5)

Explanation:

- `[a-jl-oq-z]*` match anything other than `k` and `p`
- `(k|p)?` match either `k` or `p` and capture in group `1`
- `[a-jl-oq-z]*` match anything other than `k` and `p`
- `\1` means back reference to the captured group `1` (with `( )`)
- `(?!\1)` means negative look ahead for captured group `1` (this will make sure that either of `k` or `p` which were captured does not repeat again).

Answer (score 0):

This might work - `(?<![a-z])(?![a-z]*k[a-z]*k)(?![a-z]*p[a-z]*p)[a-z]+`

Expanded:

```
 (?<! [a-z] )                  # Not [a-z] char behind
 (?! [a-z]* k [a-z]* k )       # Not 2 k's in a word
 (?! [a-z]* p [a-z]* p )       # Not 2 p's in a word
 [a-z]+                        # 1 or more [a-z] chars
```

Comment: This almost worked.  Test string was "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog pop kick".  Result set was {he, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog}.  I think the OP wouldn't want "The" to be part of the result set.

Comment: You could drop the lookbehind and wrap the rest in \b\b or ^$.

Comment: @phatfingers - why would I do that?

Comment: @Shar1er80 - I specifically put a `(?<! [a-z] )` there. As far as I know when somebody says `word` in their question it implies `boundary`. But there are many boundary's, all kinds of them. But he didn't specify. `(<![a-z])(?=[a-z])` is the one I chose, but It could be `(?<!\S)(?=[a-z])` or thousands of other characters in the set  `[^a-z]`.

Comment: @sln so if you encounter "Kick" you don't match "ick".

Comment: @phatfingers - The lookbehind is to insure the lookaheads do their job, so it can match a continuous stream of lower cased letters that satisfy the not 2 of k or p in that stream, it wasn't  meant to be a boundary for anything. It's not relevant. I  stopped trying to read-mind's a long time ago. And `\b` isn't a language word boundary, its a regex construct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your regex is intended to operate on pre-parsed words as input, rather than picking out a word from a sentence.  You want to be sure to omit 'p' and 'k' from your general set of lower-cased characters.

Regex: `^[a-jl-oq-z]*(k?[a-jl-oq-z]*p?|p?[a-jl-oq-z]*k?)[a-jl-oq-z]*$`

Example:

```
cat words.txt

a
k
p
kit
pit
tip
apt
kick
pork
tiki
word
work
kipper
wykkan
tommyRot


grep "^[a-jl-oq-z]*\(k\?[a-jl-oq-z]*p\?\|p\?[a-jl-oq-z]*k\?\)[a-jl-oq-z]*$" words.txt

a
k
p
kit
pit
tip
apt
pork
tiki
word
work
```